# Resize UILabel & UIView automatically on UIViewController in a Playground

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` in my Playground Book on which I want to position a `UILabel` & `UIView`.

In the Playground Book the user is **able to resize** the `UIViewController` by Gestures but the content (the `UILabel` & `UIView`) **does not resize**. That means that the `UILabel` & `UIView` are bigger than the actual `UIViewController` sometimes. Also the `UILabel` & `UIView` need to be dismissible at some times.

I created my `UIViewController` like this

```
let window1 = WMWindow(frame: CGRectMake(150,150,400,300))
window1.title = "View 2"

let vc1 = UIViewController()
vc1.title = "View 2"
vc1.view = UIView()
vc1.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
let nc1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)

window1.rootViewController = nc1
window1.makeKeyAndVisible()

window.addSubview(window1)
```

and my `UILabel` & `UIView` like this

```
let textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: window1.bounds.height-50, width: window1.bounds.width, height: window1.bounds.height))
textLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
textLabel.numberOfLines = 5
textLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: window1.bounds.height, width: window1.bounds.width, height: 200))
backgroundView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
backgroundView.alpha = 0.7
```

and of course I added them as subviews to the `UIViewController`.

**Now how can I change the `UILabel` and `UIView` to automatically resize depending on the size of the `UIViewController`?**

I found out that I can instead of `window1.addSubview(...)` use `vc1.view.addSubview(...)`. This line enables the user to resize the view and the subviews properly but unfortunately after a few seconds the subviews will be in the same position as the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add constraints to your views, for this to happen automatically.

For example this :

```
backgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc1.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true;
backgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc1.view.topAnchor).isActive = true;
backgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc1.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true;
backgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc1.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
```

will pin your `backgroundView` to match the exact size of the view controller.

As always, there is more in the docs :
[Understanding AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/)
[Programatically creating constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html)
[NSLayoutAnchor reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutanchor)

--
Update :
I took a more careful look at your code, and with your comment it seems that you added your views as subviews of a window. You generally shouldn't do that. You should rather do it like this : `vc1.view.addSubview(...)`. Also this `vc1.view = UIView()` is not needed, unless you wanted to provide a custom `UIView` subclass there.

Comment: that does not work in a playground because I cannot use `self`. 

Do you have another idea?

Comment: Oh! Sorry! You need to replace the `self` with however the variable in which your view controller is stored is named :) How did you add the views as subviews?

Comment: like this `window1.addSubview(backgroundView)`

Comment: also if i am moving the UIViewController it always moves to the same position after a few seconds.

Comment: getting the error with `vc.view.addSubview(...)`: `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'addSubview'`

Comment: Please check carefully - this error means that you are trying to call `addSubview` on an instance of `UIViewController` and not `UIView`

Comment: and for some reason the whole playground crashes without a proper error message when I am using this code `backgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc1.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true;`

Comment: yes `vc1` is per definition an UIViewController (`let vc1 = UIViewController()`) but I can use this instead `vc1.view.addSubview(...)`